# Phantomjs while iteration incrementation

Tags: javascript, while-loop, phantomjs, iteration, increment

i have a problem with iteration while, i have to increment the latitude and the number of the images printed, for make this script with phantomjs automatically. when i start the console it not work, it not printed nothing, maybe im wrong with the iteration, or the position of "phantom.exit"
Can anyone help me? thanks.

```
n=0;
l=10;  

while(l<22){
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open("https://www.google.com/maps/preview/@11.483083,-"+l+".145460,10z/data=!3m1!1e3", function(status) {
page.viewportSize = { width: 1440, height: 900 };

page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 250, height: 250 };

  console.log("Status: " + status);
  if(status === "success") {
  n++;
  l++;
  phantom.exit();
    page.render('img-'+n+'.png');
  }
  }); 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved, now it's working:

```
var n=0,l=10;
function to_open(){
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 1440, height: 900 };
page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 250, height: 250 };
page.open("https://www.google.com/maps/preview/@11.483083,-"+l+".145460,10z/data=!3m1!1e3", function(status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  if(status == "success") {
  n++;
  l++;
  page.render('img-'+n+'.png');
  if(n=="21") {setTimeout(phantom.exit,4000)}else{setTimeout(to_open,4000)}
}else{setTimeout(to_open,2000)}
  });
};to_open();
```